# Entity Framework - Error on Data-Bound Custom Field (Property Not Found)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

Using Entity Framework, I've extended an entity class with a "display-friendly" version of a property, in this case, `CommissionRate` which is an entity property and `CommissionRateDisplay` which is my own custom property. In my bound Web Forms control, I want to display an integer percent **3** but in the database I want to store as a decimal **0.03**.

I've created a custom field in the partial class called `CommissionRateDisplay` with a `get` and a `set` method, as below:

```
partial class SalesOrder
{
    public double CommissionRateDisplay
    {
        get { return (this.CommissionRate ?? 0) * 100; }
        set { this.CommissionRate = value / 100; }
    }
}
```

When saving the entity, I'm presented with the following error:

`A property named 'CommissionRateDisplay' was not found on the entity during an insert, update, or delete operation. Check to ensure that properties specified as binding expressions are available to the data source.`

I'd simply like to bind my custom property and have it persist the modified original in the database. `get`ting the value works just fine, but `set`ting does not.

Am I approaching this in the right way, or is there a better way? Apologies if this is a duplicate; I could not find a solution that clearly and succinctly solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `[NotMapped]` annotation to your custom property, to let Entity Framework know you don't intend it to be a column in the table.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I need. Unfortunately I'm using an incredibly old version of EF (I think it's 4.0) so the `NotMapped` attribute isn't built in. As far as I can tell, it's just a matter of adding a reference to the EF assemblies. Thanks!